# Google Play subsequent updates

Tags: android, google-play, updates

I was wondering about the Google Play behaviour when it comes to subsequent updates of an app.

I will explain myself.

Let's say I publish an app on Google Play with version code 1. A user installs it and everything's good.

I then update to version 2, but the user doesn't update...maybe the phone has been off for some time...

Then I come up with version 3.

Next time the user's phone will update the app, will it go through version 2 and then 3, or will he/she get version 3 at once from 1?

I need to know because my app relies on features that I have released in previous versions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As long as you app permissions remains the same, latest uploaded apk file gets installed on your phone. Incase you change permissions, user must manually navigate to play store and upgrade the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be upgraded straight to version 3.

At one time, there is only one live version of the multiple apks that you might have uploaded. So, the latest build always gets installed on the user's phone, regardless of which version is currently installed.